# X Windows special programs: do some of these still exist? Which ones?

Tags: x11

I recall that X11 provided a number of "fun" programs accessible via unix. For instance, if you use the command `xeyes`, an interface will pop up of cartoon-like eyes which follow your cursor everywhere.

This still works on my most update version of X11.

But I remember so many more of these fun little commands. For instance, there is:

(A) `xsnow` which causes snow to fall on your desktop, with the santa option

(B) `xsol` which would begin a solitaire GUI you could interact with

(C) `xmille` was something similar, and allow you to play the game Mille Borne

(D) `xroach` caused cockroaches to crawl all over your screen, with the squish option allow you to click/squish these buggers

(E) `xphoon` would show the moon as it appears today

(F) `xpenguins` has penguins appear

(G) `oneke` had something to do with cats and dogs

Question 1: Does anyone else still use these? The only command which still works for me is `xeyes`. Which updates do I need to use the others?

Question 2: Have I forgotten any of these types of X11 commands?